# NSString crash when release

Tags: iphone, crash, nsstring, release

I use NSString to append strings, but when I release the "cacheStr" NSString, the iphone simulator crash. 
Where should I put the release code ?

init code : I use three NSString to append content of the dataArray.

```
NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *cacheStr = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *tmpStr = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *notiyStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"This is a test message!"];
dataArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      @"currency1.png",
                      @"currency2.png",
                      @"currency3.png",
                      @"currency4.png",
                      @"currency5.png",
                      @"xxxxxx",
                      @"currency1.png",
                      @"currency2.png",
                      @"currency3.png",
                      @"currency4.png",
                      @"currency5.png",
                      @"xxxxxx",
                      nil];
```

append string code : use for loop to append strings.

```
int isFailed = 0;
int countOfDataArray = [dataArray count];
if (!isFailed) {
    for (int i=0; i < countOfDataArray; i++) {
        if ([[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"xxxxxx"]) {
            tmpStr = [cacheStr stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n", [dataArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
        else {
            tmpStr = [cacheStr stringByAppendingFormat:@"value %d : %@\n", i+1, [dataArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
        cacheStr = [tmpStr copy];
        [tmpStr release];
    }
}
tmpStr = [notiyStr stringByAppendingString:cacheStr];
```

release code : when I add [cacheStr release], the simulator will crash...

```
[dataArray release];
[notiyStr release];
// [cacheStr release];     /*  crash ... */
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its more simple to declare a NSString like this

`NSString *tmpStr = @"This is a test message!";`

then no need to release it,when you dont use alloc

Comment: If I must use NSString initWithFormat XXX ... the NSString stll need to release. Maybe I should use c/c++'s sprintf to do this, the NSString stringByAppendingString seems to be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
dataArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  @"currency1.png",
                  @"currency2.png",
                  @"currency3.png",
                  @"currency4.png",
                  @"currency5.png",
                  @"xxxxxx",
                  @"currency1.png",
                  @"currency2.png",
                  @"currency3.png",
                  @"currency4.png",
                  @"currency5.png",
                  @"xxxxxx",
                  nil];
```

is strange! You are allocating a mutable array and assigning the pointer pointing to that array to an array which you do not own. It is probably already (auto)released when you try to use it. Therefore `int countOfDataArray = [dataArray count];` will result in `countOfDataArray` being zero. Therefore `cacheStr` is never set. Still it shouldn't crash on releasing the `cacheStr`.

Change it to:

```
NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"currency1.png",
                  @"currency2.png",
                  @"currency3.png",
                  @"currency4.png",
                  @"currency5.png",
                  @"xxxxxx",
                  @"currency1.png",
                  @"currency2.png",
                  @"currency3.png",
                  @"currency4.png",
                  @"currency5.png",
                  @"xxxxxx",
                  nil];
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: Don't mind but "Therefore int countOfDataArray = [dataArray count]; will result in countOfDataArray being zero." This is wrong. Count will be there because it will assign new memory address of new array and will work.

Comment: What I meant: `countOfDataArray` will be 0 because `dataArray` is nil and the method `count` sent to nil results in 0.

Comment: `countOfDataArray` will not be 0 because dataArray will be pointing to new memory location and it will be 12. Please check practically if you doubt.

Comment: This depends where the allocation occurred. If the allocation and the call of count aren't in the same scope I doubt that.

Comment: If you try his code pasting in project it shows 12 count. So There is some misunderstanding. Please check your self and let's end this topic here.

Answer (score 0):

dont use [NSString alloc] init. To use NSString value=@"Message"; No need to release it.

Comment: If I must use NSString initWithFormat XXX ... the NSString stll need to release. And thanks for your support.